# is it an 'anti-pattern' to grab mobile configuration from a remote, 'configuration' server?

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, software-design

I'm new to mobile development and was wondering if it is an anti-pattern to have a remote, configuration server in order to 'configure' a mobile client.  The idea is to avoid configuration details [except the URL to the configuration server] with the mobile distribution and rather connect to the configuration server to grab other details such as third party keys, service endpoints, etc.  Any thoughts. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your main concern will be securing that server; what is to stop an attacker from connecting to that server in order to retrieve API keys etc.

Comment: It's possible to use `.mobileconfig` files similarly, so not really anti-pattern.

Comment: So the idea is to have the connection be secure (TLS/SSL) and to have some sort of authentication; something like a username/password that only mobile client would know (hardcoding them, configuring them, or having some sort of key generation algorithm that the phone would know]).  Although that brings up the question what's to stop malicious users from hacking into the phone and getting the auth details... which brings us up to the first point.  So that's part of the reason I ask is how do professionals do it? by configuring the phone directly or through a config server??

Comment: thanks for the comments, btw @Paulw11

Comment: and thank you @l'L'l

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are able to secure connections to the the configuration server, using a username/password and SSL encryption it's not an anti-pattern. It would save you from publishing new applications versions just to update some configuration.

What does however sound like a bad idea to me is keeping third-party API keys inside a mobile application.

Can you guarantee that each an every user using you application will not use the keys placed inside the mobile application to use the third party service to their own ends? I don't think anyone can make that guarantee.